# Kitten UI (React Native) Input Styles incorporate in React Native Google Places Auto Complete

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm trying to use the exact style of [React Native Kitten UI](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/autocomplete/overview#autocomplete) Auto Complete with Theme(light and dark) capability in the [React Native Google Places Auto Complete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete?activeTab=readme)

Have tried a few things like custom style in `<GooglePlacesAutoComplete style={-CUSTOM-STYLE-}`, but I believe there would be a lot of customization to be done.

Do we know of any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Got a little closer to where I wanted. Still not able to style based on `onFocus`. But anything is better than nothing.
Will keep updating this answer.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
import { Text, useTheme } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { withStyles } from '@ui-kitten/components';

const GooglePlacesInput = () => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const theme = useTheme();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current?.setAddressText('');
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Text category='label' appearance='hint'>Place</Text>
            <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                ref={ref}
                placeholder='Search'
                onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                    // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                    console.log(data, details);
                }}
                query={{
                    key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
                    language: 'en',
                }}
                styles={{
                    poweredContainer:{display:'none'},
                    textInput:{
                        color:theme['text-basic-color'],
                        backgroundColor:theme['background-basic-color-2'],
                        borderColor: theme['border-basic-color-4'],
                        borderWidth:1,
                        height:40,
                        marginTop:5
                    }
                }}
            />
        </>

    );
};

export default withStyles(GooglePlacesInput);
```